# Display Position: Relative Compatibility Issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, positioning

Display="Position: Relative;" is Juggling in IE (Browser Mode: IE7/8/9 - Document Mode: Quirks) But If I changed Document Mode from Quirks to IE7/8 or even 9 it's working fine. How to set through CSS this issue? Please see sample code below:

CSS

```
.aFlyOut{
    padding: 10px;
    bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #a6adb3;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 9999;  
}

.aFlyoutCollapse
{
    background-image:  url("/vtpOnline/images/settings.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 100% 50%;  
    cursor:pointer;
    width:40px;
    height: 20px;
    text-indent: 21px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}   

.aFlyoutExpand
{
    background-image:  url("/vtpOnline/images/settings.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 100% 50%;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:40px;
    height: 20px;
    text-indent: 21px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.aFlyoutButton{
    height: 12px;
    float: right;
    width: 38px;
    cursor: hand;
    padding-right: 4px;
}
.aFlyout{
    float: right;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #a5acb2;
    right: 6px;
    #right: 8px;
    padding: 0px;

}
.aFlyoutHeader{
    padding: 4px 6px 3px 0;
    background: url("/vtpOnline/images/actionFlyoutHeaderIcon.gif") #090999 no-repeat;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-indent: 23px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.aFlyoutLinkWrapper{
    padding:5px;
}
.aFlyoutLinkWrapper a{
    padding: 5px;
    color: #010356;
    font-size: 11px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.aFlyoutLinkWrapper a:hover{
    color: #0060ff;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
.aFlyoutRefreshLink{
    background: url("/vtpOnline/images/addNote.png") no-repeat 0 50%;
    text-indent: 12px;
    #text-indent: 10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="aFlyoutButton" id="aFlyoutLink"> 
  <!-- Action Flyout Action Button -->
  <div class="aFlyoutExpand" title="Actions" id="aFlyoutButton" onMouseOver="aFlyoutExpand()" onMouseOut="aFlyoutExpandCollapse()" onClick="aFlyoutExpandCollapse()"> </div>
  <div id="aFlyout" class="aFlyout" style="display: block;" onMouseOver="aFlyoutExpand()" onMouseOut="aFlyoutExpandCollapse()"> 
    <!-- Action Flyout Action Header -->
    <div class="aFlyoutHeader" style="color: #FFFFFF;font-size: 11px !important;"> Actions </div>
    <!-- Action Flyout Links Panel -->
    <div class="aFlyoutLinkWrapper" style="width: 100px;"> <a class="aFlyoutRefreshLink" href="#" id="j_id_jsp_2094016106_1:REFRESHNOTESCREENACTION" name="j_id_jsp_2094016106_1:REFRESHNOTESCREENACTION" onClick="aFlyoutExpandCollapse();;A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id_jsp_2094016106_0','j_id_jsp_2094016106_1',event,{'oncomplete':function(request,event,data){Richfaces.showModalPanel('AddNoteModalPanel');setValues();return false;},'similarityGroupingId':'j_id_jsp_2094016106_1:REFRESHNOTESCREENACTION','parameters':{'j_id_jsp_2094016106_1:REFRESHNOTESCREENACTION':'j_id_jsp_2094016106_1:REFRESHNOTESCREENACTION'} ,'actionUrl':'/vtpOnline/faces/order/edit/default.jsf'} );return false;">Notes</a> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When i mouse hover it shows:

[image]

However, it should be as:

[image]

Comment: Please show your code. (I'm asking because I see big troubles in what you've posted so far)

Comment: @Linus Caldwell, as requested i've updated the sample code.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `position: absolute` somewhere? And what's the `#right` and `#text-indent` for?

Comment: But where you think position: absolute should be added? and #right & #text-indent is for the alignments purpose only.

Comment: `position: absolute` positions an element absolutely while `top`, `right` etc. sets the position relative to it's next parent with `position: relative`. So as far as I understand the pop menu should have `position: absolute` and the container `position: relative`. And there is no `#right` or `#text-indent` property. Properties cannot start with `#`.

Comment: Okay, let me give it a try and i'll let you know if this works.

Comment: Nopes, still no luck... not working still out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone, it has been resolved; please see following code reference. I've changed position from relative to absolute and set top & height to fix the positioning.

```
.aFlyOut{
   position: absolute;
   top: 28px;
   height: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Document mode quirks means that you're essentially running a pre-IE6 rendering engine. A good solution to solve this is to add a doctype to the top of your HTML document. This will put the browser in standards mode by default, and will allow your position:relative; to work as expected.

The simplest doctype is the HTML5 one:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Put that on line 1 of your HTML. There is no way to force standards mode via CSS.

Comment: if i add <!DOCTYPE html> it destroys the whole page layout, BUT fixed this issue. However I can't compromise on whole page for this, so is there any other way around?